# Как добавить стили к выводу таблицы?

Tags: php, html, css

Есть код для вывода таблицы из Oracle:

```
<?php
// коннект к базе
$conn = oci_connect("user", "pass", "database");

// выполнение запроса
$sql = "select * from tc_uid.jkd_check";
$res = OCIParse($conn, $sql);
oci_execute($res);

//начало отрисовки таблицы
echo "<TABLE BORDER=1";
echo "<TR>";

// отрисовка шапки таблицы
for ($i = 1; $i-1 < oci_num_fields($res); $i++) {
echo "<TH>";
echo oci_field_name($res,$i);
echo "</TH>";
}

// отрисовка и заполнение самой таблицы
while ($row = oci_fetch_row($res)) {
echo "<TR>";
for ($i = 0; $i < $fields=count($row); $i++) {
echo "<TD>".$row[$i]."</TD>";
}
echo "</TR>";
}
echo "</TR></TABLE>";  
oci_close($conn)
?>
```

Требуется добавить стили css к выводу этой таблицы (строки из файла table.css):

```
.sortable {border-left:1px solid #c6d5e1; border-top:1px solid #c6d5e1;    
 border-bottom:none; margin:0 auto 15px}
.sortable th { border:1px solid #c6d5e1 } /*text-align:left;      

color:#cfdce7;*/
.sortable th h3 {padding:6px 8px 8px}
.sortable td {padding:4px 6px 6px; border-bottom:1px solid #c6d5e1; border-         
 right:1px solid #c6d5e1}
 .sortable .head h3 {background:url(images/sort.gif) 7px center no-repeat;     
cursor:pointer; padding-left:18px}
.sortable .desc h3 {background:url(images/desc.gif) 7px center no-repeat;   
cursor:pointer; padding-left:18px}
.sortable .asc h3 {background:url(images/asc.gif) 7px  center no-repeat; 
cursor:pointer; padding-left:18px}
.sortable .oddrow td {background:#ecf2f6}
.sortable td.evenselected {background:#ecf2f6}
.sortable td.oddselected {background:#dce6ee}
```

Вопрос в том, как это сделать? Куда прописывать данные стили?
Простите за глупый вопрос, не очень понимаю данный вывод. Помогите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто добавляете класс к элементу который выводите с помощью php. Например:

```
echo '<TABLE class="sortable" BORDER="1">';
```

Только в echo используйте одинарную скобку, а класс/стиль - двойную для избежания ошибок. 
Ну и не забудьте подключить сам файл со стилями.